# Which version of guava is compatible with java 1.7

Tags: java, guava

My project can't compile with the lasts Gauva library as it seems to be compiled with Java 1.8 and I'm using Java 1.7 in my project.

Which version of Guava is compatible with Java 1.7?

Comment: Based on guava github "Requires JDK 1.6 or higher (as of 12.0)." You can use any version after 12.0

Comment: Not really a recommendation request. This kind if question has one answer.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic at all!  I have this question too.  I must use Java 7, and I want to use Guava.  What version works?  This is not asking for a recommendation.

Comment: Starting from version 22, you can use the android version which supports Java 1.7: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v22.0/README.md

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All versions of Guava up to version 20 are compatible with Java 1.7.

From [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/guava-discuss/ZRmDJnAq9T0/-HExv44eCAAJ) email,

> Guava 20 (to be released in early 2016) will be the final Guava release to support Java 6, or even Java 7. Guava 21 (ideally mid-2016) will require Java 8.
>
> With version 21 we will also kick off a new fork, presumably called guava-android. It will maintain Java 6 compatibility, allowing it to be used for Android apps supporting a minimum version of Gingerbread.

Answer (score 4):

Versions 12.0 through 20.0 are "compatible with Java 1.7".

From [ReleaseHistory · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReleaseHistory):

> - Release 21.0 requires JDK 1.8 or newer.
> - Releases 12.0 through 20.0 require JDK 1.6 or newer.
> - Releases 1.0 through 11.0 require JDK 1.5 or newer.